# Joda - create DateTime with timestamp of special timezone

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I try to convert a timestamp that represents an UTC time to a `DateTime`... Like this:

```
Date d = getDate();
DateTime j = new DateTime(d.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);

// d.toString() =>Mon Jan 05 23:00:00 MEZ 2015
// j.toString() => 2015-01-05T22:00:00.000Z
// but I expected it to be 1 hour later
// btw, my local timezone is UTC+1...
```

How can I convert a timestamp to a datetime, only knowing the timestamp and the timezone of timestamp? For my use case, I know the timestamp is UTC time and I want to create a `DateTime`with it...

**WHAT I WANT**

Let's say, my Date is 01.01.1970 12:00:00... So it's 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds (43200000). Just a point in time without timezone...

Now I want to create DateTimes with this Date. So I relate the Date to a timezone.

From the given Date I want to create DateTimes like following:

- UTC DateTime: with time 12:00:00 in UTC timezone
- UTC+1 DateTime: with time 12:00:00 in UTC+1 timezone and time 11:00:00 in UTC (of course, the date representation of DateTime is changed by this, it's one hour less)
- UTC+2 DateTime: with time 12:00:00 in UTC+2 timezone and time 10:00:00 in UTC (of course, the date representation of DateTime is changed by this, it's two hours less)

Meaning, I define manually the timezone of the timestamp...

Comment: Why would you expect it to be one hour later? It's 23:00 in MEZ, which is presumably UTC+1...

Comment: Because I want to set the UTC time of the DateTime to the timestamps time... And not my local time to the timestamps time... I want to explicitly define the timezone of the timestamp... Btw, all my Dates are now representing UTC times only... So I will only convert UTC timestamps to DateTimes...

Comment: Note that `Date` doesn't inherently have a timestamp - `Date.toString()` just shows your default time zone.

Comment: It's *very* unclear what your actual data source is, or why you expected the result to be an hour later. Do you understand that 23:00:00 MEZ and 22:00:00Z are the same point in time? Do you understand that `Date` has no concept of a time zone?

Comment: Ok. That's somehow confusing... Date has NO timezone but actually it's UTC+1? I thought, it has no timezone... So I expect it should be possible to create following `DateTimes` from an example date like 01.01.2014 00:00:00: (1) UTC with time 00:00:00, (2) UTC+1 with time 00:00:00, (3) UTC+2 with time 00:00:00 and so on... No timezone in date means I can define a timezone for a `DateTime`... Hopefully, this explains why I'm expecting a different result...

Comment: No, `Date` doesn't have a time zone, but `toString()` always displays the point in time represented by the `Date` instance using your default time zone (it's *just* how it's converting it to a string though). Note that `DateTime` *does* have a time zone. But your example is incorrect - a `Date` represents an instant in time. You can view convert that instant in time into different `DateTime` values with different time zones, but they'll all have different *local* times.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I edited my question, to explain what I want... What I want is, to create DateTimes with the same local time, by just giving them the the date and a timezone... Is that possible?

Comment: You've still misunderstood what's in a `Date`. It's *just* a point in time. There's no "local time" to be preserved - because that only makes sense when you *apply* a time zone. It's still not clear what `Date` you're getting to start with - I can't help you without more context.

Comment: I edited my question again... I think, I get the point... Maybe, I should say, that I want to CONVERT a timestamp/Date? Still not clear what I want to achieve? From a timestamp of 43200000 (12 hours) I want to create local `DateTimes` that all represent the local time of 12 o'clock... But of course they don't represent the same time anymore...

Comment: The word "timestamp" usually refers to an instant in time. If you really mean a time of day, it's worth saying so. You should represent that as a `LocalTime`. You can then combine that with a `LocalDate` to get a `LocalDateTime`, and combine *that* with a `DateTimeZone` to get a `DateTime`. We still don't have any idea of your real context though.

Comment: Ok... That really helps... Actually, after rethinking about it, the most important information for me was, that `Date.toString` formats the Date with the local timezone... I think, I won't need to convert values... With this information...

Comment: @prom85 Please search StackOverflow before posting. The issues explained to you by Jon Skeet have been covered by *hundreds* of other Questions and Answers.